# Problem with displaying changes (4-space code indent added) in edit-history?

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

The revision list for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1165064/list) does not show (colour/highliht) the changes introduced in revision 2. The changes in question were some four-space indents added to mark code.

Answer (score 2):

The change would probably be as simple as modifying the background of the code blocks. I light gray/green would probably be best, keeping with the theme of green for changes, but being grayish to indicate the code block.